# chmod 777: how to make all files become "RWX"

Tags: linux, command-line, chmod

I want to change permission of each files in a directory. I've been using `chmod 777` but its wasting time if I have 50 files.

How to make all files inside directory become `rwx` without change them one by one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chmod -cR 777 *

Will change all the files including subdirectories recursively (R option) including subdirectories, but also report on when it makes a change (c option).

Rather than changing all the files with too wide permissions, you might want to change the ownership instead.

```
sudo chown -hR tomcat
```

The line above changes owndership to a tomcat application server, you need to figure out which user your webserver is using. You can easily see that by doing

```
ps aux
```

(The h option is for changing the owndership of a symbolic link if encountered, but not the files it linkes to)

Answer (score 5):

**What you are doing is more than likely unsafe and the below command should only be invoked if you completely accept the security issues.**

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 '{}'* \;
```

This will recursively go through the current directory and each subdirectory and change the permissions accordingly; if I haven't made it clear enough, this is a very bad idea (777 permissions)

Answer (score 1):

This script will execute the command for all files in the current directory:

```
sudo find . -name "*" | awk '{print("chmod 777 "$1)}'| /bin/sh
```

To test the script first, you can just output the statements without piping them to the shell to be executed:

```
sudo find . -name "*" | awk '{print("chmod 777 "$1)}'
```

This same pattern using awk is generally useful for performing batch shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
chmod 777 *
```