# Accessing Ubuntu-Made file on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I have a dual partition on my computer and frequently use both sides. Whenever I mount my windows partition and save a file that I made in the linux environment, I always make sure to make the command

```
sudo chmod a+rwx filename
```

to make sure I can access it on the windows partition since I've had trouble with that in the past. (Creating a file in linux and attempting to open it in windows and being unable to due to lack of access). Is there any way to avoid having to run the chmod command every time I create a file?

Comment: Ummm, yes, just don't run it. There is no reason why you should have this kind of issue. What filesystem are you saving on? How are you accessing the linux partition from Windows? What permissions do newly created files have?

Comment: [Don't](http://superuser.com/a/162929/144700) [`chmod`](http://superuser.com/a/269346/144700) [`777`](http://askubuntu.com/a/20110/41)!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would like to create a partition using the NTFS file system and use it for the files you want to 'transparently' access from both systems. I'm  saying that because - based on my past experiences - is easier to have a linux system dealing with 'windows stuff' than otherwise.

Comment: Agreed... Here is a tutorial I found helpful, all about setting up a dual-boot system with an NTFS partition so that your files can be easily accessed in both OS: http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony